# setTimeout does not work in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, settimeout

I am writing a little dynamic HTTP server based on `net` module (homework assignment) that sends `408` response if the server user didn't call `response.end()` after two seconds.

No matter what I tried, the function is not invoked. Here's another code that demonstrates what I tried to do in my program:

```
var NET = require("net"); 
var server = NET.createServer(function(socket){
    console.log("In connectionHandler");
    socket.on('data',function(data) {
        console.log("New data");
        var timer = setTimeout(function(end){
            console.log("INSIDE TIMEOUT FUNCTION");
            if (end) {
                return;
            }
            throw new ERROR.ServerError('408',' Request Timeout','The \
            server has timedouted');
            },10,true);
        for (var t = 0 ; t < 100000000000 ; t++){}
        clearTimeout(timer);
    })

});


server.listen(4000, function() {
    console.log("server bound");
});
```

So, timeout is set to 10 ms followed by a very long loop, yet this doesn't work.

Why this is happening?

Comment: `for (var t = 0 ; t < 100000000000 ; t++){}` - what the hell?

Comment: It's to give setTimeout time to execute the callback function before the process terminates

Comment: Active waiting is *always* a horrible and wrong thing unless you are on a microcontroller which you aren't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The callback is never called because setTimeout is asynchronous. The timer gets activated when this "turn" is over, and you clear the timeout before the end of the turn.

You should read first about javascript's event driven architecture. [This tutorisal](http://javascript.info/tutorial/events-and-timing-depth) would be a good start. This is essential to solve your timeout problem.

Comment: I read the tutorial, still can't tell what my problem is. Also, I've tried removing clearTimeout and it still doesn't invoke the function...

Comment: Remove the long for loop (since it is useless, you dont have to "give setTimeout time to execute the callback function before the process terminates", it doesnt terminate until you have pending timeouts) and remove the clearTimeout() as well. It will get inside the callback.